# Is it possible to assign a ReadOnly variable in a child class?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, readonly

Suppose I have this parent class:

```
Public MustInherit Class Parent

     ' ReadOnly instance variables:
     Protected ReadOnly str1 As String
     Protected ReadOnly str2 As String
     Protected ReadOnly str3 As String

     ' constructor:
     Public Sub New()
     End Sub
End Class
```

I want to assign these variables in a child class' constructor, and I want them to be `ReadOnly` so they cannot be changed once assigned, like this:

```
Public Class Child
     Inherits Parent

     ' constructor:
     Public Sub New()
          MyBase.New()

          ' can't assign the ReadOnly variables here!
          ' compile error:  'ReadOnly' variable cannot be the target of an assignment
          Me.str1 = "asdf"
          Me.str2 = "qwerty"
          Me.str3 = "foobar"
     End Sub
End Class
```

How can I do this? If it's not possible, why not?

Answer (score 2):

Pass them through to the parent constructor:

```
Public MustInherit Class Parent

     ' ReadOnly instance variables:
     Protected ReadOnly str1 As String
     Protected ReadOnly str2 As String
     Protected ReadOnly str3 As String

     ' constructor:
     Public Sub New(s1 as String, s2 as String, s3 as String)
        str1 = s1
        str2 = s2
        str3 = s3
     End Sub
End Class
```

Your class then can do:

```
Public Class Child
     Inherits Parent

     ' constructor:
     Public Sub New(s1 as String) ' You can pass these through if needed
          MyBase.New(s1, "qwerty", "foobar")
     End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hey @Reed -- Is it possible to pass a variable as an argument to `MyBase.New` in `Child`? I'm getting the error: `Implicit reference to object under construction is not valid when calling another constructor`.

Comment: @IanCampbell Check my edit - is that what you mean?  You can't use `Me....` variables there, though, since the object hasn't been created yet.  You *can* use shared variables...